# ICA Session object is not returned while launching Citrix Via VBscript

Tags: session, citrix

We are trying to launch a Citrix desktop instance using :

Set ICO = CreateObject("Citrix.ICAClient") ICO.Address = Addr ICo.TransportDriver = "TCP/IP" ICO.InitialProgram = "#testing- " ICo.WinstationDriver ="ICA 3.0" ICO.Username = "tester" ICo.Domain = "ASIA" ICO.SetProp "ClearPassword", "hello" ICO.SetProp "Launch", "TRUE" ICO.Connect ICO.Session.Mouse.SendMouseDown 1,0,400,400 'waitfor 30 secs ICO.Logoff

it generates error(Object required: 'ICO.Session') while using session object ICO.Session.Mouse.SendMouseDown 1,0,400,400

obviously it is not returning session object.

Simulation is enabled:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Citrix\ICA Client\CCM]
"AllowSimulationAPI"=dword:00000001
How to return the session object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `EnumerateCCMSessions` to get the session objects, and iterate over the session objects using `GetEnumNameCount` to get the session names:

```
Set icaClient = CreateObject("Citrix.ICAClient")
sessionHandle = icaClient.EnumerateCCMSessions()
numSessions = icaClient.GetEnumNameCount(sessionHandle)

For ct = 0 To numSessions - 1

sessionID = icaClient.GetEnumNameByIndex(sessionHandle, ct)
icaClient.StartMonitoringCCMSession sessionID, True

'SessionServer = 0,
'SessionUsername = 1
'SessionDomain = 2
sessionInfo = icaClient.GetSessionString(1)
If lcase(sessionInfo) <> lcase(strWindowsUser) Then
    icaClient.Disconnect()
End If

icaClient.StopMonitoringCCMSession sessionID 

Next

icaClient.CloseEnumHandle sessionHandle
```

> A. EnumerateCCMSessions: API to enumerate all the sessions running on the machine returning the list of session IDs.
>
> B. StartMonitoringCCMSession: API to start the live monitoring. You must pass the session ID of the session which you want to monitor. Once this is done, it is then possible to use other ICA Simulation APIs.
>
> C. StopMonitoringCCMSession: API to stop monitoring the session. When finished with monitoring, this API should be called. Doing so cleans up any resources used by ICO.

**References**

- [VBS: ActiveX component can't create object: 'Citrix.ICAClient' errror on 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325231/1113772)
- [Citrix Quick Launch](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX122536)
- [ICA Client Object Changes in the Version 11.2 XenApp Plug-in](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX123616)
- [ICA Object SDK: Citrix ICA Client Object API Specification Programmer’s Guide](http://www.citrix.com/static/cdn/archivedsdks/icaobjectsdk/ICA_Client_Object_Guide_v10x.pdf) (pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for a session to be created. Right after connection session is not yet created. Either hardcode some timeout between calling ICO.Connect and SendMouse, or wait for an event, such as onConnect or onLogon.